# How to add notifications, when there is any change in WebView App?

Tags: android

How to add notifications to `WebView` App when there is any changes in the web url. i.e. if user creates a new task in `webview` then I need to notify user.

Answer (score 0):

Implement WebViewClient and extend onPageFinished() , so you can even see url:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: I need a push notification whenever any data changes in webview.

Comment: so you should look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ for adding FCM to your app